# How to pass a model to a template rendered from a route in Ember 1.6

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set a model in a rendered template from a route. The model is being captured correctly via the template call:

```
{{#each itemController="user"}}
  <div {{bind-attr class="isExpanded:expanded"}}>
  <div><button {{action "sayHello" this}}>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</button></div>
```

and my Route:

```
Newkonf.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  isExpanded: false,

  actions: {
   sayHello: function(myModel){

      alert('first name: ' + myModel.first_name); // <- this works
      // this.render('edit-user', {model: myModel});  <- doesn't work but not sure since this leads me to susupec 
      // it might https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1820
      // this.set('model', myModel}); <- doesn't work
      this.render('edit-user');
    }
  }
}
```

the handlebars is:

```
going to edit user here first name: {{first_name}}
```

### Edit 1

I can update the message in UsersRoute and it will update accordingly. I kind of though since I specified UserController that it would cause UserRoute to take precedence but I guess not.

Here is my router:

```
Newkonf.Router.map(function() {
  // this.resource('posts');
  
  this.route('about', { path: '/about'});
  this.resource('users', { path: '/users'}); 
});
```

### Edit 2

I had to do my modal.js.hbs like this:

```
within modal for you:
{{model.first_name}}
```

because this didn't work:

```
within modal for you:
{{first_name}}
```

and not sure why.

Here's my Route:

```
Newkonf.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  actions:{
    somePlace: function(item){
     alert('here i am in somePlace: ' + item.last_name); // <- this works
     var modalController = this.controllerFor('modal');
     modalController.set('model', item);
     var myjt=modalController.get('model');  
     console.log('my value:' + myjt.first_name); // <- this works
     this.render('modal', {
       into: 'application',
       outlet: 'modal3',
       controller: modalController
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and there is no  controller.

Comment: will you show your router?  And are you in the users route when you click the action?

Comment: Is your main goal to replace the users template with a different template?

Comment: I'd ultimately like to render a template in a new 'modal' outlet and have this not replace the current outletted template but just want to be able to pass model now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering to a particular outlet requires both the outlet be named, and the outlet to be in view when you attempt to render to it.

In the case of a modal, having it live in the application template is generally a good choice since the application is always in view.

```
  actions: {
    openModal: function(item){
      var modalController = this.controllerFor('modal');
      modalController.set('model', item);
      this.render('modal', {  // template
        into: 'application',  // template the outlet lives in
        outlet: 'modal',      // the outlet's name
        controller: modalController  // the controller to use
      });
    }
  }


  App.ModalController = Em.ObjectController.extend();
```

In the case above I'm rendering the template `modal`, into `application`, using the outlet named `modal` ( `{{outlet 'modal'}}`) and I created a controller to back the template I'm rendering.  In the process I set the model on the controller, which would be used in the template.

You can read more about modals: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

And here's the example:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pudegupo/1/edit

Comment: thx kingpin2k - that makes a lot of sense. One thing I noticed was that I needed to use sometihng like `{{model.first_name}}` in my modal template and am not really sure why.... Might be a separate question. Perhaps it was because I didn't use `App.ModalController = Em.ObjectController.extend();` and just used what would be a proxy controller (if that mekes sense.

Comment: yeah, are you using a plain Em.Controller.extend?  If so it won't automatically proxy from the controller scope down to the model.

Comment: hmm... but it worked in your sample code on jsbin... I'm sure it's probably I just don't understand. Are you saying that how you used it should work? I am also on 1.6beta5 - maybe I'll go back to 1.5 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I probably misunderstood what you said, what's your proxy controller?

Comment: thx kingpin2k - I don't have a controller but have included my code (which is very similar to yours) and it outputs with `{{model.first_name}}` but not just `{{first_name}}`. I really appreciate your help

Comment: interesting, I thought this.controllerFor('nonExistantController') blows up, something about if you are explicitly naming a controller you should have defined it. in 1.5.1 it yells at me http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pudegupo/3/edit

Comment: If you're using Ember inspector, after it inserts it into the page, you can see what type of controller modal is (pretty sure it's just Em.Controller)

Comment: yeah, I think you're right. I'll open new question regarding other problem.