# How to pass arbitrary data to render in an Ember template?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

So we're trying to render custom content into a template.

We have this template:

```
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="popup modal error">
    <header>
      <p>Error!</p>
      <div class="close" {{action 'closeModal'}}>
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      {{message}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.. with this application route:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions:

    displayError: (message) ->
      @render 'error-modal', 
        into: 'application'
        outlet: 'error-modal'
        model: Ember.Object.create message: message
```

And in our controller we're calling:

```
@send 'displayError', 'Error message.'
```

The modal pops up just fine, but the message isn't being rendered. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: We have this question too!

Comment: i think a similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111263/how-to-pass-a-model-to-a-template-rendered-from-a-route-in-ember-1-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the common controller (to the template and the modal) for setting the error message:

```
displayError: (message) ->
  @controller.set('errorMessage', message)
  @render 'error-modal', 
    into: 'application'
    outlet: 'error-modal'
```

In the template: `{{errorMessage}}`.